# maven-processor-plugin listing the annotation processors to ignore

Tags: configuration, maven-3, annotation-processing

Is there a way to use the maven-processor-plugin (or any other plug-in) to execute annotation processors listing the ones to skip? I have little control on the processors my dependencies might use but I do know the one I want skipped.

The only option in the [usage page](http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/docs/usage.html) is to list the ones you want to include but not the other way around.

Is there a way to do this in Maven?

Comment: I opened an issue in the plug-ins issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/issues/detail?id=45

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of the maven plugin, but of the availability of `javac` options. According to the [javac reference on annotation processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#processing)

> Processors are located by means of service provider-configuration files named   META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor on the search path. Such files should contain the names of any annotation processors to be used, listed one per line. Alternatively, processors can be specified explicitly, using the -processor option.

So for now there's no way to remove an annotation processor, just whitelist the ones you want to run.

Comment: The Maven plugin has a configuration option to whitelist the annotation processors and then pass those to the javac. The plug-in team agreed that this feature would make sense. Probably auto detecting to build the list and then removing the blacklisted ones before passing to javac.